# Frame Navigate in Windows Phone C#

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-phone-8.1, frame

I use to move between pages

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Pages.AccountSettins));
```

everything works well on the emulator.
but it does not work on your phone! constantly knocks application.
earlier all worked well.
what is the problem?

Comment: Try replacing that for `((Frame) Window.Current.Content).Navigate(typeof(Pages.AccountSettings));`, or maybe try that leading to other page or debug step by step, a constructor in AccountSettings might be throwing an exception.

Comment: @Felype no., did not help! :(
no errors detected. just knocks application using Frame.Navigate()
I have other application where everything works well.
and this application in the emulator works fine

Comment: Okay, try adding a NavigationFailed event and popping a message with `NavigationFailedEventArgs.Exception.Message`, if this fails then an exception is being thrown somewhere and not being catched, if so you can try to wrap this line in a try/catch block and display the message. If you get to know at least what is happening that ought to be a tip on where to start looking. Uncaught exceptions will always crash WinRT apps, but if you get to catch it, you can display the message, read what it is about and the app won't crash and will tell you what's possibly wrong.

Comment: @Felype thank you! Now I will try this.. but why this work in emulator? and why it works in my other projects?

Comment: @Felype try{}catch{} return: The program '[3448] test.exe' has exited with code -1073741795 (0xc000001d) 'Illegal Instruction'.

Comment: @Felype now error is:
The program '[3176] test.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Comment: did you solve your problem? I'm having the same issue too

Comment: @NadaNaoushi pls help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really still don't know whats causing the issue, but I solved my problem by calling the dispatcher to handle`Frame.Navigate`:

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MyPage)));
```

hope it helps